# Android Studio doesn't change layout from landscape to portrait

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on my university project in Android Studio and I've had this problem: the menu doesn't change passing from landscape to portrait and viceversa.

This is the code of the floating action menu portrait (menu_piu.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/menu_floating"
    android:layout_width="285dp"
    android:layout_height="315dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
    app:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
    app:menu_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:menu_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
    app:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
    app:menu_fab_size="normal"
    app:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
    app:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
    app:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
    app:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
    app:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
    app:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
    app:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_left"
    app:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
    app:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
    app:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
    app:menu_labels_paddingBottom="4dp"
    app:menu_labels_paddingLeft="8dp"
    app:menu_labels_paddingRight="8dp"
    app:menu_labels_paddingTop="4dp"
    app:menu_labels_position="right"
    app:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_left"
    app:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
    app:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
    app:menu_labels_textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:menu_labels_textSize="14sp"
    app:menu_openDirection="up"
    app:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
    app:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
    app:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
    app:menu_shadowYOffset="3dp"
    app:menu_showShadow="true">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton

        android:id="@+id/aggiornamento_stato"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ico_aggiornamento_stato"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
        app:fab_colorRipple="#FFFFFF"
        app:fab_label="Aggiornamento stato" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton

        android:id="@+id/ricerca"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ico_ricerca"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
        app:fab_colorRipple="#FFFFFF"
        app:fab_label="Ricerca" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton

        android:id="@+id/profilo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ico_profilo"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
        app:fab_colorRipple="#FFFFFF"
        app:fab_label="Profilo" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/lista_amici"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ico_amici"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
        app:fab_colorRipple="#FFFFFF"
        app:fab_label="Lista amici" />

</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

The other menu (menu_piu_land.xml) is the same, but without the floating action menu. It should show the buttons horizontally to simplify the project.

I include these files in the layout\activity_home.xml (`<include layout="@layout/menu_piu"/>`) and in the land\activity_home.xml (`<include layout="@layout/menu_piu_land"/>`).

When I tested the app in the Android Studio emulator, it changed the view, but not the menu: the home is shown in the same way as it started. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is the code of activity_home.xml and land\activity_home.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.punta.geopost.home">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <include layout="@layout/menu_piu"/> // <include layout="@layout/menu_piu_land"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.punta.geopost">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyA8fzesjeCV0_X3PolMIXc9DbZ1er05-SA"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".login"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".home"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".profilo"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ricerca"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".stato"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".amici"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
</application>
```

Comment: can you post activity_home.xml and land/activity_home.xml?

Comment: Updated @NicolaGallazzi!

Comment: This is the code of activity_home.xml and land\activity_home.xml. From your edit seems you have the same code for portrait and landscape, I'm confused

Comment: Yes, it's the same! 'Cause I just want to change the menu with the <include> part! Take a look at the end!

Comment: Now I get it, activities xmls seem ok, can you post the project to a public github link?

Comment: I never did that, but I can try. :)

Comment: I should have done it, @NicolaGallazzi! Here it is: https://github.com/puntat/Geopost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in your manifest. This flag prevents your activity to be recreated on configuration changes, so your landscape layout is never selected from your activity. Remove the flag from activity "home" in your manifest.xml

```xml
<activity android:name=".home" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nicola! You saved me!

Answer (score 1):

Learn about "Android Activity Lifecycles". They are fundamental to the flow of your app.
Whenever an activity changes its orientation the onCreate() method is restarted, so you have make use of *savedInstanceState*. You have to check for these changes in there.
And post your Manifest file here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Updated with the manifest.
I'm not calling the orientation change in my Home activity, it's added in my .xml.

Answer (score 1):

The right folders are:

- res/layout and res/layout-land,
- the files should have same name, the same you use in onCreate of Activity, example setContentView(R.layout.menu_piu);

[More details here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources)

Happy coding and learning!

P.S.: avoid hard coding, move strings to strings.xml, values to dimens.xml

Comment: This is correct but I guess that Mattia problem stays elsewhere :)